# Rmarkdown html document not rendering using the task scheduler

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to schedule `rmarkdown` `html` documents but they never end up rendering.

I can run the code below like a normal program and it works. The `html` document gets saved into my working directory, but when I try scheduling it, it doesn't render.

```
library(rmarkdown)

rmarkdown::render("MonthlyReport.Rmd")
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: What are you using to schedule execution?

Comment: If you are using Rscript to execute your script, you'll need to load the `methods` package first.

Comment: @JanLauGe I have tried taskscheduleR. It says it's running but never actually does the task. taskscheduleR runs other Rscripts just fine, including one that sends an email. I have also tried batch files and using the windows task scheduler but that doesn't work. I will try the methods package.

Comment: I see. Would you mind posting your `taskscheduleR` code here? Ideally, edit your answer and include it there so people can try to reproduce your problem. Cheers!